# Using ifelse Within apply

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, dataframe, apply

I am trying to make a new column in my dataset give a single output for each and every row, depending on the inputs from pre-existing columns.

In this output column, I desire "NA" **if** any of the input vales in a given row are "0". **Otherwise** (if none of the inputs are 0), I want the output for that row to be the number of unique values of the inputs.

I thought that the solution would use an **ifelse** function nested within an **apply** function, but I get an error that I do not understand.

```
data$output <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {ifelse(x == 0, NA, length(unique(x)))})
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "output", value = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  : 
>     replacement has 3 rows, data has 4

I do not know why the replacement has 3 rows, as I thought apply just does the same function to each of my 4 rows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to check if any of the variables in a row are 0, so you need to use `any(x==0)` instead of `x == 0` in the `ifelse` statement:

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) {ifelse(any(x == 0), NA, length(unique(x)))})
# [1]  1 NA  2
```

Basically `ifelse` returns a vector of length n if its first argument is of length n. You want one value per row, but are passing more than one with `x==0` (the number of values you're passing is equal to the number of columns in your data frame).

Data:

```
(data <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(1, 0, 1)))
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 0
# 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `n = length(x)`. `ifelse` will return `rep(NA, n)` if `TRUE` otherwise `rep(length(unique(x)), n)`. Therefore `apply` will output a matrix. `data$output <- apply(...` tries assign a matrix (your result) into a column in your `data.frame`, `data$output`. This is the cause of your error.

Your code will run if you just assign your output to a variable instead

`out <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {ifelse(x == 0, NA, length(unique(x)))})`

If you are not expecting a `class(matrix)` as your output, but rather a vector, then there is something wrong with the logic of your function.