# how create indicators vector crossponding to a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column with elements: 1,2,3,4 how I can make 4 vectors i=1,2,3,4 which is 1 if that row is i, and -1 if it is not i.

example

```
mode
 1  
 3
 1
 2
 4
 1


   i1     i2     i3      i4     
   1     -1      -1      -1
  -1     -1       1      -1
   1     -1      -1      -1
  -1      1      -1      -1
  -1     -1      -1       1
   1     -1      -1      -1
```

I hope it is clear, for example first row is 1 so i1 is 1 and others are -1, second row is 3 so i3=1 and others -1 and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables/5048727 and the many linked questions in the sidebar which show alternative methods.

Comment: @Andreas if I knew how do that, I wouldn't ask!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ifelse Within apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769325/using-ifelse-within-apply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of 4 vectors, this generates a matrix.

```
vec_mode <- c(1,3,1,2,4,1)

matr <- matrix(-1, nrow = length(vec_mode), ncol = max(vec_mode))
matr[cbind(seq_along(vec_mode), vec_mode)]<- 1

colnames(matr) <- paste0('i', seq_len(max(vec_mode)))

matr

     i1 i2 i3 i4
[1,]  1 -1 -1 -1
[2,] -1 -1  1 -1
[3,]  1 -1 -1 -1
[4,] -1  1 -1 -1
[5,] -1 -1 -1  1
[6,]  1 -1 -1 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` is to create new columns with `row_number` and value (`val`) 1. `spread` it to wide format with `fill = -1` to fill missing values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   mutate(row = row_number(), 
          val = 1,
          mode = paste0("i", mode)) %>%
   spread(mode, val, fill = -1) %>%
   select(-row)

#  i1 i2 i3 i4
#1  1 -1 -1 -1
#2 -1 -1  1 -1
#3  1 -1 -1 -1
#4 -1  1 -1 -1
#5 -1 -1 -1  1
#6  1 -1 -1 -1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(mode = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L)), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```