# Using an ifelse function in a lapply/apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, apply, lapply

Trying to apply a function to a large dataset. Specifically, trying to apply the mean of the lowest 1000 times (df$time) set before the date (df$date) found in that row. *Applying this function on a small portion worked*

However, because the dataset is so large, I want to restrict the apply to just the 1% of rows where df$wr is true.

This is the code I wrote so far with mean1000 as the intended name of the new variable and the data set split based on name (25 categories):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
 mean1000 = lapply(
    split(df, df$name), function(y) 
      df$y$mean1000 = apply(y, 1, function(x) {ifelse(x["wr" == TRUE], 
        mean(sort(df$time[df$date < x["date"]])[2:1000]), NA)})) %>% 
  unlist()
)
```

Result:

df1 is created, but it's just a table with 0 observations of 1 variable (mean1000)

The error message is 25 times the following:

```
1. Unknown or uninitialised column `y`.
```

I mostly followed the [guidelines as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769325/using-ifelse-within-apply?newreg=871b5478129a4c01bd9fe8fa614c13c8), but those solutions are less complex/layered than what I'm trying to do. How can I adjust the code?

Data:

```
| # | time | date      | id1 | id2 | rank | name  | wr   |
|---|------|-----------|-----|-----|------|-------|------|
| 1 | 2408 | 2022-06-04| a8m2| pr9w| 24   | City01| TRUE |
| 2 | 2503 | 2022-06-25| b6p5| ur1r| 226  | City01| FALSE|
| 3 | 2672 | 2022-05-07| c8k1| py5l| 371  | City01| FALSE|
```

The desired result is to have an extra column added in which the mean calculated (*mean(sort(df$time[df$date < x["date"]])[2:1000])*) is added when the wr value is TRUE.

Edit to show the adjustments made to Parfait's answer:

```
    # SORT DATA BY NAME AND DATE
    df <- with(df, df[order(name, date),]) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)
    df <- as.vector(df)
    
    # CONDITIONALLY CALCULATE MEAN BY GROUP
    df$mean1000 <- by(df, df$name, function(sub) {
      # ITERATE THROUGH EVERY DATE ROW WHILE CONDITIONALLY ADJUSTING BY wr FLAG
      mean1000 <- ifelse(sub$wr == TRUE, sapply(
        sub$date,
        # SUBSET AND CALCULATE MEAN
        FUN=\(dt) mean(sub$time[sub$date< dt][2:1000], na.rm=TRUE)
      ), NA_real_)
    })
    # CONVERT VECTOR BACK TO DATA FRAME AND RENAME COLUMN
    df <- data.frame(df$id1, df$id2, df$id3, df$time, df$date, df$rank, df$name, df$wr, as.numeric(unlist(df$mean1000)))
    colnames(df) <- c('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'time', 'date', 'rank', 'name', 'wr', 'mean1000')
```

Comment: You should include a sample dataframe `df` in your question.  It doesn't need to be the real one, but it should have the same structure (and give the same problem when used in your code),

Comment: You need to rethink your approach. `split` returns a list of data frames, not *a* data frame, so df1 will be a list, not a data frame.  Secondly, your function inside the lapply should reference an element of the list it is passed with just `y`, not `df$y`.  There are probably other errors in your code too, but as @user2554330 says, it's difficult to be precise about your problems without a concrete set of test data  (and your expected output) to work with.  All the same, welcome to SO!

Comment: @user2554330 I have added a sample in my original post, hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: @Limey I appreciate the feedback and happy to be here. Split is what I used to keep the various categories (City01 in the sample) apart to perform the analysis, as the means are independent and separate by category. About your second point, does that mean df$y$mean1000 should instead just be y$mean1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) which is very similar to `split` + `lapply` but more streamlined. Then run an embedded `sapply` for rowwise mean conditional calculations.

```r
# SORT DATA BY NAME AND DATE
df1 <- with(df1, df1[order(name, date),]) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

# CONDITIONALLY CALCULATE MEAN BY GROUP
df1$mean100 <- by(df1, df1$name, function(sub), {
    # ITERATE THROUGH EVERY DATE ROW
    mean1000 <- sapply(
         sub$date,
         # SUBSET AND CALCULATE MEAN
         FUN=\(dt) mean(sub$time[sub$date < dt][2:1000], na.rm=TRUE)
    )
    # CONDITIONALLY ADJUST BY wr FLAG
    mean1000 <- ifelse(sub$wr == TRUE, mean1000, NA_real_)
}) |> as.vector()
```

Comment: Since the reason to restrict to `wr == TRUE` is to reduce computation, wouldn't it make sense to do that filtering at the start, instead of the end?

Comment: Maybe but I don't know your data fully to know how `wr` breaks out by `date` and `name`. Even your attempt ran `ifelse` *after* the mean calculation. Really you could nest `sapply` inside `ifelse` and avoid *mean1000* assignment. Does this solution work?

Comment: @Parfait thanks for the more efficient function! Using it on the data set (probably should have specified that it's 590k rows) took around 60 mins rather than over 24 hours for my old code (before giving an error message). I was also going to ask about filtering before calculating, but for now, I'm getting a different error:

`Error in vec_size():
! x must be a vector, not a <by> object.`

Comment: Since `by` returns a special list object, run `as.vector` at the end. See edit.

Comment: @Parfait That fixed some of it yeah. Had to make some small adjustments to make it work (added to what I did to my post, couldnt edit the code in your answer for some reason), but with the ifelse nested, it all runs in about 2,5 minutes so that's much improved. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Most SO answers are never exactly used but need slight adjustment to actual use case! Happy coding!